# StackTimer: Set post-specific timers on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: script

#### Screenshots (click to enlarge)

[image: Timer dialogue]

<sup>Just click the *timer* button under any post to set a timer.</sup>

---

[image: Timer queue in top nav]

<sup>View pending timers in your top bar at any time. If any timer has elapsed, the icon turns orange. The [new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network?cb=1) is also supported as of 0.3.4, as is Stack Overflow's top bar.</sup>

#### About

Ever wanted to remind yourself of a particular post later on? With this userscript, you can set post-specific timers that notify you through the top bar of any Stack Exchange site when they expire.

You might find this useful if you ever want to review a post after downvoting, or if you perform any moderation actions (e.g. post notices) and want to check for changes in a given period of time.

**Usage**

- A **timer** link appears below every post, near other post actions such as the **share** button. <sup>New in 0.3.0: even in review queues!</sup>
- You can enter a time and reason for setting a timer, then save it to your top bar. *Note that the timer list updates on page load, so your timer may not appear straight away*.
- When a timer expires, the icon turns from grey to orange, and remains so until the **dismiss** link is clicked.

#### Contact

For issues, consider using the [dedicated bug tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/TheIoTCrowd/StackPostTimer/issues). Otherwise, I may generally be reached in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/227128/aurora0001); feel free to ping.

#### License

This is released under [the Unlicense](https://github.com/TheIoTCrowd/StackPostTimer/blob/master/LICENSE), with icons derived from Font Awesome.

#### Download / Install

[**Direct Install Link**](https://github.com/TheIoTCrowd/StackPostTimer/raw/master/timer.user.js) (requires [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/))

Comment: I've posted a few issues on github. I'd appreciate it if you'd review them

Comment: @Mibac Thanks for raising issues, and apologies for not reviewing them earlier (I've been busy the last few days). I'll respond further on GitHub.